# Calculating number of pages when number per page is not equal for all pages

Tags: calculus, functions, problem-solving

Usually I'll lurk and post around at Stack Overflow, since I'm a programmer mostly, but I'm currently pulling my hair out over the lack of my mathematical knowledge.

I'm building a pagination, which can have an unequal amount of objects per page, and I need to calculate the maximum number of pages.

Let me explain in a bit more detail with an example:
Usually, I have 9 objects per page, but this can vary.
When a user does a search, he gets all his search-results first (`true_results`), and appended to that list, all other objects from the database (`all_other_results`), not included in the first set, so the page never looks empty, even with strange filters by the user.
On the page design itself, it breaks every third object into a new row, so there are 3 objects per row. After the `true_results` there is a horizontal line, splitting up the two sets. Since it would look ugly, if I have, for example, 7 `true_results`, it's two full rows and one object in the third row.

When I would only show 9 elements, it shows another row with just another two objects from the `all_other_results`-set, so I'm showing 10 instead on that page, to make the last row of `all_other_results` complete. Every following page will have 9 objects (just the last one can have less, but that's fine with rounding up).

What I know:

- amount of `true_results`
- amount of `all_other_results`
- default amount of `objects_per_page`
- objects per row

How do I find out the total number of pages?

This is what I have so far, which is basically me giving up and trying to brute-force it, without any luck. In some cases, I'm off by 1 (in either direction..). It looks like that:

```
total_1 = floor(true_results / objects_per_page)
total_2 = floor(all_other_results / objects_per_page)
if ((total_1 + total_2) * objects_per_page) < (true_results + all_other_results):
    return total_1 + total_2 + 1
else:
    return total_1 + total_2
```

If anyone can help me out or give a push in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**
Since I wasn't very clear, I'll show some examples:

- When the total of both lists is divisible by 3 (=`rows_per_page`), all pages show 9 objects per page, and the calculation is straight forward
- When the `true_results` isn't divisible by 3, the complication starts, since one of the `true_results` rows *can either have just one or two objects*, instead of three.

  - When `true_results` is 7: first page shows 10 results
  - When `true_results` is 8: first page shows 11 results
  - When `true_results` is 9 (or 6): first page shows 9 results
  - When `true_results` is 11: first page shows 9 results, second page shows 11 results (two objects of `true_results` and 9 of `all_other_results`)

Comment: it seems your main issue is calculating number of objects on the page that has both true results and all other results. Calculations for all other pages are straightforward. Can you describe what happens if you have 8 true results? 10? 6?

Comment: I don't think you are accounting for the page that has some true_results and some all_other_results. You should probably count how many rows are needed for true and for other, and then use something like rows_per_page to find out the number of pages. Mind you, it is not clear to me whether you are being entirely consistent about the number of rows per page.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Vasya and @JaapScherphuis! I've edited my questions to make it more clear with some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what language are you using but assuming it has a ceiling function.

```
total_1 = floor(true_results / objects_per_page)
remainder = true_results % objects_per_page
other_remaining_objects=0
if (remainder>0):
   remaining_rows=ceil(remainder/objects_per_row)
   other_remaining_objects=objects_per_row * (objects_per_page/objects_per_row-remaining_rows+1)
total_2 = floor((all_other_results - other_remaining_objects) / objects_per_page)
remainder = (all_other_results - other_remaining_objects) % objects_per_page
if (reminder > 0):
    return total_1 + total_2 + 2
else:
    return total_1 + total_2 + 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not giving me correct results, but I think it's going to the right direction. When I've 11 `true_results` and 96 `others`, the page-count is 12, but the 12th page is blank and the 11th page has the last 6 results.

Comment: @some_blub: so 1 page with true results, 1 page with mixed (1 row of true results and 3 rows of all) . This leaves us with 96-9=87 all objects which will require 10 pages or 12 pages total, no?

Comment: Damn, you're right! I had an error in the part, which was responsible to get the objects from the database, which was giving me too less results because of a stupid typo in my list-comprehension. Maybe this also was responsible of me pulling out my hairs.. I fixed that and it seems to be perfectly on point now with your function! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @some_blub Glad I was able to help. I happen to do some programming myself :)